# Easy Way to Get Averages Based on Names in List

Tags: r

Is there any easy way to get the averages of items in a list based on their names?  Example dataset:

```
sampleList <- list("a.1"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b.1"=c(3,4,1,4,5), "a.2"=c(5,7,2,8,9), "b.2"=c(6,8,9,0,6))
sampleList
$a.1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b.1
[1] 3 4 1 4 5

$a.2
[1] 5 7 2 8 9

$b.2
[1] 6 8 9 0 6
```

What I am trying to do is get column averages between similarly but not identically named rows, outputting a list with the column averages for the `a's` and `b's`. Currently I can do the following:

```
y <- names(sampleList)
y <- gsub("\\.1", "", y)
y <- gsub("\\.2", "", y)
y <- sort(unique(y))
sampleList <- t(as.matrix(as.data.frame(sampleList)))
t <- list()
for (i in 1:length(y)){
   temp <- sampleList[grep(y[i], rownames(sampleList)),]
   t[[i]] <- apply(temp, 2, mean)
}

t
[[1]]
[1] 3.0 4.5 2.5 6.0 7.0

[[2]]
[1] 4.5 6.0 5.0 2.0 5.5
```

A I have a large dataset with a large number of sets of similar names, is there an easier way to go about this?

EDIT:  I've broken out the name issue into a separate question.  It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976569/variable-length-core-name-identification)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is *shorter*. You didn't say exactly how big your actual data is, so I"m not going to make any promises, but the performance of this shouldn't be terrible:

```
dat <- do.call(rbind,sampleList)
grp <- substr(rownames(dat),1,1)

aggregate(dat,by = list(group = grp),FUN = mean)
```

(Edited to remove the unnecessary conversion to a data frame, which will incur a significant performance hit, probably.)

If your data is *crazy* big, or even just medium-big but the number of groups is fairly large so there are a small number of vectors in each group, the standard recommendation would be to investigate `data.table` once you've `rbind`ed the data into a matrix.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `aggregate`.  However, is there any way to account for the occasional row name of the form `a.1.X`, where `X` is a variable-length string, which also exists?

Comment: @learner Hard to say without knowing how you want `a.1.X` grouped. With all the other `a`s? In their own group...?

Comment: My bad - I should probably just edit above to better explain the naming here.

Comment: @learner A cleaner route might be to split the naming question off into a separate question, since the two aren't completely connected. Up to you...

Comment: you could just grep("a") it will capture all of a.1.X

Answer (score 4):

I might do something like this:

```
# A *named* vector of patterns you want to group by
patterns <- c(start.a="^a",start.b="^b",start.c="^c")
# Find the locations of those patterns in your list
inds <- lapply(patterns, grep, x=names(sampleList))
# Calculate the mean of each list element that matches the pattern
out <- lapply(inds, function(i) 
  if(l <- length(i)) Reduce("+",sampleList[i])/l else NULL)
# Set the names of the output
names(out) <- names(patterns)
```

Comment: +1 smart I always forget that lapply works just as well with names as it does with the list itself as the argument.

Comment: That's pretty ninja. (You typed `ind` instead of `inds`.)

Comment: This is cool.  Could I ask you to post it as a response to a name specific question?  I've linked it in an edit.