# Variable Length Core Name Identification

Tags: r

I have a data set with the following row-naming scheme:

```
a.X.V
where:
a is a fixed-length core ID
X is a variable-length string that subsets a, which means I should keep X
V is a variable-length ID which specifies the individual elements of a.X to be averaged
. is one of {-,_}
```

What I am trying to do is take column averages of all the `a.X's`.  A sample:

```
sampleList <- list("a.12.1"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b.1.23"=c(3,4,1,4,5), "a.12.21"=c(5,7,2,8,9), "b.1.555"=c(6,8,9,0,6))
sampleList
$a.12.1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b.1.23
[1] 3 4 1 4 5

$a.12.21
[1] 5 7 2 8 9

$b.1.555
[1] 6 8 9 0 6
```

Currently I am manually gsubbing out the `.Vs` to get a list of general :

```
sampleList <- t(as.data.frame(sampleList))
y <- rowNames(sampleList)
y <- gsub("(\\w\\.\\d+)\\.d+", "\\1", y)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

This is one half of 2 issues I've encountered in a workflow.  The other half was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975794/easy-way-to-get-averages-based-on-names-in-list).

Comment: what do you mean by 'manually gsubbing'? do you mean multiple calls to `gsub`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vector of patterns to find the locations of the columns you want to group.  I included a pattern I knew wouldn't match anything in order to show that the solution is robust to that situation.

```
# A *named* vector of patterns you want to group by
patterns <- c(a.12="^a.12",b.12="^b.12",c.12="^c.12")
# Find the locations of those patterns in your list
inds <- lapply(patterns, grep, x=names(sampleList))
# Calculate the mean of each list element that matches the pattern
out <- lapply(inds, function(i) 
  if(l <- length(i)) Reduce("+",sampleList[i])/l else NULL)
# Set the names of the output
names(out) <- names(patterns)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could consider messing with your data structure to make it easier to apply some standard tools:

```
sampleList <- list("a.12.1"=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
  "b.1.23"=c(3,4,1,4,5), "a.12.21"=c(5,7,2,8,9), 
   "b.1.555"=c(6,8,9,0,6))
library(reshape2)
m1 <- melt(do.call(cbind,sampleList))
m2 <- cbind(m1,colsplit(m1$Var2,"\\.",c("coreID","val1","val2")))
```

The results looks like this:

```
head(m2)
  Var1    Var2 value coreID val1 val2
1     1  a.12.1     1      a   12    1
2     2  a.12.1     2      a   12    1
3     3  a.12.1     3      a   12    1
```

Then you can more easily do something like this:

```
aggregate(value~val1,mean,data=subset(m2,coreID=="a"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`R` is poised to do this stuff if you would just move to `data.frame`s instead of `list`s. Make Your 'a', 'X', and 'V' into their own columns. Then you can use `ave`, `by`, `aggregate`, `subset`, etc.

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, sampleList), 
           do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(sampleList), '\\.')))

#         X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X1.1 X2.1 X3.1
# a.12.1   1  2  3  4  5    a   12    1
# b.1.23   3  4  1  4  5    b    1   23
# a.12.21  5  7  2  8  9    a   12   21
# b.1.555  6  8  9  0  6    b    1  555
```